# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility fails with Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I have selected source and destination on step 1, logged in with TFS administrator credentials on both sides. Selected "I want to migrate version control data" on step 2.

When i come to step 3, it immediately fails with error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. The list of team projects is empty.

[screen dump](https://imageshack.com/i/p4qyUN3gp)

The log file OVSMU.log says:
2014-08-06 17:49:37,004 [1] ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.ProjectSelectionViewModel.loadProjectWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUTFSMigration\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\ProjectSelectionViewModel.cs:line 312
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

How to proceed? Is there anything I can do to find out the real cause, why the team project list is empty?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in version OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe.

You can download it from visualstudiogallery

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2/file/132237/5/OVSMU-V1.0.1.006.exe

Comment: Thank you! I will check it next time we migrate something in the TFS, quite soon.